# Why does preventDefault() of a click event also prevent my form from submitting?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I have a simple HTML form:

```
<form name="form" id="form" method="post" action="">
    <label for="input_text"><span>Input Text:</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="input_text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then I prevent the default click action, because I want to use AJAX to handle the submission instead of the regular method.

```
// prevent page refresh
var form = document.getElementById('form');
function stopDefault(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
form.addEventListener('click', stopDefault, false);
```

However this causes some unexpected behaviour.

If I get the submit button and make an anonymous onclick function for it, the onclick function will fire even if the form is submitted by hitting enter when the cursor is inside a form field, i.e. it will also fire by *not* clicking on submit. Here's an example:

```
var button = form.submit;
button.onclick = function() {
    console.log('clicked');
}
```

Strangely enough this onclick function will also catch non-click form submissions. On the other hand, if I try to catch an actual form submission...

```
form.onsubmit = function() {
    console.log("submitted");
}
```

...it won't fire!

Why is that?

To me it seems more logical to handle form input onsubmit rather than onclick, but I guess that just isn't how it works.

Also, as a side note, interestingly it doesn't matter whether the target event for the preventDefault() method is the actual form or the submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent page refresh you just need this

```
// prevent page refresh
var form = document.getElementById('form');
form.onsubmit = function() {
  console.log("submitted");
  return false; // this prevents page refresh
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N2gxh/)**

Comment: So why doesn't form.onsubmit fire while preventDefault is in play? And how is this better than preventDefault aside from letting me use the form.onsubmit function?

Comment: Because to submit, you need a click. And your saying preventDefault inside click function which means _whatever this click is gonna trigger dont do it_ and it means submit for the form on the button click. Even hitting enter inside a from element fires click action because it leads to submit button click.